# difference between 電卓{でんたく} and 計算機{けいさんき}

Tags: word-choice

Please look at the Texas Instruments [TI-108](http://education.ti.com/en/us/products/calculators/elementary-calculators/ti-108/tabs/overview). Is that a 電卓{でんたく} or 計算機{けいさんき}? My guess is that the most basic calculators are 電卓, and that as more scientific functionality is added (like graphing), a calculator becomes a 計算機? So, the TI-108 is a 電卓、right? Devices such as the [TI-36X](http://education.ti.com/en/us/products/calculators/scientific-calculators/ti-36x-pro/tabs/overview) and the [TI-84 Plus](http://education.ti.com/en/us/products/calculators/graphing-calculators/ti-84-plus/features/features-summary) are 計算機?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「[電卓]{でんたく}」 is originally short for 「[電子式卓上計算機]{でんししきたくじょうけいさんき}」, meaning that the two words refer to the same thing -- an electronic pocket (or desk) calculator.

We also use the word 「計算機」 to mean the same thing as above.

Thus, you may call any one of the TI products you mentioned using any one of the three words I mentioned.

Additionally, you could also specifically use the newer word 「グラフ電卓」 or 「グラフ[関数]{かんすう}電卓」 to refer to the ones with a graphing function.

関数 means "function" in math, not the "function" as in "graphing function".

Answer (score 0):

I would call all the TI series shown above 「電卓」rather than 「計算機」.
Indeed, 「電卓 (calculator)」is a small, portable「計算機 (computer)」.