# Should I call the basic calculator app on iPhone 電卓app or 計算機app?

Tags: words

I just fired-up the basic calculator app on an iPhone. Is that called 電卓app or 計算機app?

Were I to get a more sophisticated app that calculated stuff like logarithms, would the name change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between 電卓{でんたく} and 計算機{けいさんき}](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18374/difference-between-%e9%9b%bb%e5%8d%93%e3%81%a7%e3%82%93%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8f-and-%e8%a8%88%e7%ae%97%e6%a9%9f%e3%81%91%e3%81%84%e3%81%95%e3%82%93%e3%81%8d)

Comment: @istrasci Not really. I was just wondering what a Japanese person calls the calculator app on his/her smartphone. If 5 people were to evenly split a lunch bill, would one think "I need my 電卓app to do the division."? My reflex is to call it the "電卓app", but I'm not a native speaker, I just like the sound of でんたく and I don't think it makes much difference(?), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official calculator app [was called 計算機](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/guide/iphone/iph1ac0b5cc/ios), although it looks like it is no longer installed by default. People use these words interchangeably, and I suppose the majority of people do not even remember which is the official name of the default app. The calculator pre-installed on Windows is called 電卓, and so is the calculator installed on my Android phone.

Strictly speaking, 電卓 and 計算機 are not exactly the same. 電卓 only refers to that small gadget you can buy even at a 100円ショップ, whereas 計算機 technically also includes PCs, mainframes and supercomputers. However, although "sophisticated" ones are basically called 計算機, 関数電卓 has been established as a set phrase, and even iOS's 計算機 has a mode called 関数電卓. So if you want something like the one below, it's usually called 関数電卓 rather than 関数計算機.

[image]